# Serve images using web server

Tags: image, nginx

I have webserver up and running serving several GB of images to our users. Is there any way in which they can view smaller size image and when they click on it to download it should be full sized image.

Image for Viewing should be -> Compressed or small so they can go through different images quickly.
When they download it should be full sized HD image.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You can use "image_filter" [1] directive to automatically generate thumbnails or reduced images.

Additionally, you can combine it with "proxy_store" [2] and "try_files" [3] directives to save already processed images on disk and serve them first, saving your CPU cycles by not resizing each requested image.

[1] http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html

[2] http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

[3] http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files